# My refineryCMS does not send emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, refinerycms

I am trying to configure my application for sending emails of notification, but I do not know why, the emails does not send it.

The log return me :

```
There was an error delivering an inquiry confirmation:
503 STARTTLS command used when not advertised
```

My email.rb file :

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
}
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method ||= :smtp
```

thanks.

Comment: Try turning off encryption in your outbound SMTP settings

Answer (score 1):

As @FreddyWetson mentioned, turn off encryption in your SMTP settings in the ***environment file***.

The environment files are `config/environments/[environment].rb` where environment can be like production, test, development etc.

Refer to: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Section: 6, 6.1 and 6.2

> :enable_starttls_auto - Set this to false if there is a problem with
>   your server certificate that you cannot resolve.